# How do I install axis2 into tomcat6?

Tags: 10.04, tomcat6

I'm trying to install axis2 onto tomcat6 and I'm having some difficulties.

I've installed tomcat6 using apt and I've downloaded the axis2.war file and placed it in 
`/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/`.

From the instructions I'm following, tomcat should now unpack the war file and create and axis2 directory in `webapps/` but this is not happening.

I can see the default tomcat page on `http://localhost:8080/` but I cannot see the axis2 page on `http://localhost:8080/axis2/`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out. In tomcat6, you need to set-up an admin user and go to the manager application to launch war files. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy `axis2.war` under the path `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps` which is my case, you can check in your system.  But make it sure that you are not copying else where or inside webapps any other folder like root (`/`).

Once you've copied `axis2.war` in the above path then restart the tomcat6 server from path `/usr/share/tomcat6` by using

```
./shutdown.sh
```

and

```
./startup.sh.
```